# How to I read input from a file and use it in an sqlplus query?

Tags: python, shell, sqlplus

I am trying something like

```
   select customer_id, order_id from order_table where purchase_id = 10 OR 
   purchase_id = 25 OR 
   ...
   purchase_id = 25432;
```

Since the query is too big, I am running to variety of problems... if I run the entire query in a single line, I am running into the error:

```
SP2-0027: Input is too long (> 2499 characters) - line ignored
```

If split the query to multiple lines, the query gets corrupted, due to the interference with line numbers printed for each line of the entered query. If I disable line numbers, SQL> prompt at each line is troubling me.

Same error if run the query from a text file  `SQL> @query.sql`
(I did not face such issues with mysql in the past but with sqlplus now).

I am not an expert in shell-script nor in python. It would be of great help if I can get pointers on how I can put all the purchase_ids in a text file, one purchase_id per line and supply it to **sqlplus** query at script-runtime.

I did sufficient research, but I still appreciate pointers as well.

Comment: did you try using IN clause to shorten the query:
`select customer_id, order_id from order_table where purchase_id IN (10,25,2542);`

Comment: In seems to be IN() clubbed with 2a) of @AnthonyKong seems to be good option.    Currently working on a shellscript, where in a for-loop I am making a connection to database. For each connection it takes around 15 seconds, so the result might take hours.

Answer (score 1):

1) **Syntax change**:

Try to use 'in (10,25,2542, ...)' instead of a series of 'OR'. It can reduce the size of the sql statement

2) **Logic change**:

Syntax may delay the inevitable, but the exception will still occur if there are a lot of id to exclude.

2a)

A straight-forward fix is to break the query down into batches. You can issue a select query per 50 purchase IDs until all IDs are covered.

2b)

Or you can look into a more generalised way to retrieve the same query result. Let's assume what you actually want to see is a list of 'unconfirmed order'. Then instead of a using a set of purchase IDs in the where clause, you can add a boolean field 'confirmed' to the `order_table` and select based on this criteria.

Comment: have you thought of cost of post processing required(which is way too high according to me) and data accuracy(doubtful)?

Answer (score 1):

another idea:

Create a table "query_ids" (one column) and input all your `order_id` from the `WHERE` clause.

New query would be:

`select customer_id, order_id from order_table where purchase_id = ( select * from query_ids);`

Comment: Good idea. But I do not have rights to create a new table.   Secondly, I will have to somehow transfer the purchase_ids to the new table. Back to square one.  However, this seems very useful if I repetitively (at least twice) run the queries based on the new table.